# South of Hell: Car in Purgatory

Tags: plot-explanation, props, south-of-hell

In episode 6 of [South of Hell](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4147780/), the main characters are in Purgatory waiting for a bus that will take them to Hell.  The main characters escape to a place on the edge of Purgatory and there is a car there that (presumably) will drive them to the land of the living.

The car has a "D" sticker, which I first associated with Germany, but the show takes place in South Carolina and there are no connections to Germany in the plot; it must mean something else otherwise it's a horrendous continuity error.  So I must have missed something that explains why a car in Purgatory would have a "D" on it.

What does the "D" sticker signify?

[image]

For comparison purposes, here's a photo of an Germany sticker.

[image]

Comment: *"What does the "D" sticker signify?"*  Dead?  BTW - does the German sticker have a slight bulge on the left and two prongs jutting out below it like that one?

Comment: Edited to show a German sticker. No prongs.

Comment: In that case, I'd suspect that it was put on the car to cover the original sticker.  Was the car featured in the show in a way that suggests it might appear again, or was it a 'one off'?

Comment: There are no 'chekhov's guns' in the series; I watched all eight episodes and the car / sticker never appeared again.  There are no prominent characters with initial 'D' that would make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your association with Germany is correct.

Not only is "D" the [country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_vehicle_registration_codes) for Germany, but also the car itself is of German origin.
It is a "[Trabant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trabant)" (aka "Trabi"), which was produced in East-Germany and the most common car there.
It became a symbol for the fall of the inner-German wall, since many East Germans explored western Europe with the Trabant (there is a [movie about that](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101960/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) as well).

After Germany's reunion in 1990 the owner replaced the East-German country code "DDR" with the West-German "D" (or just put the new sticker on top, as it seems to be the case here). 
Although many people sold their Trabi as soon as possible and bought a western car, the Trabant was quite popular for others and [spread to the western world, including the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trabant#1990s_and_beyond). That explains its way to South Carolina.

Why this car was in that scene, I can not tell. 
[ An easy explanation would be, it simply looked exotic to the producers. 
I could also speculate about deeper meanings and an analogy regarding the East bloc equals hell/purgatory and the western world being the land of the living, but that would go too far.]

**To sum it up:** I think, there is neither a deeper meaning in the sticker itself, nor a continuity error here.